# Linking Zaproxy to Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I get this error when trying to build my project in Jenkins

C:\Zaproxy>java -Xmx512m -jar C:\Zaproxy\zap-D-2017-02-20.jar -daemon -host 127.0.0.1 -port 8090 -config api.key=ZAPROXY-PLUGIN -dir "C:\Users\user11\OWASP ZAP"

Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Zaproxy\zap-D-2017-02-20.jar
ERROR: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

The command is executed from a .bat file launched by the zaproxy plugin in Jenkins.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: for some reason the jar file renamed itself to zap-D-2017-02-20.jar.jar along the line explaining why it wouldn't get to it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `C:\Zaproxy\zap-D-2017-02-20.jar` doesn't have the right privileges. Or the plugin doesn't have the privilege to handle the file. I suggest you to check the privilege.